# Fraction rules A/B/C vs B/C/A

Tags: fractions

I have all my fraction rules written down, but these two confuse me...

$$
\frac{\;\;A\;\;}{\frac{B}{C}} \equiv{\frac{\;AC\;}{B}}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\frac{B}{C}}{\;\;A\;\;} \equiv{\frac{\;B\;}{CA}}
$$

These do not give the same answers, and I am wondering what the rules are for using them? Are $$A>B>C$$ and $$B>C>A$$ the two conditions?

Comment: It's just what the convention for the meaning of the notation is.

Comment: ok so i just get to pick whichever one helps me solve my algebra, even though they do not give the same answer?

Comment: The first one is correct. The second one is incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Unfortunately, your comment is mistaken - one of the two rules is *wrong* as written.

Comment: @user2355058 why did you choose `\frac{}{\cfrac{}{}}` instead of `\frac{}{\frac{}{}}`?

Comment: Because it makes them the same size, is that not the goal?

Comment: Division is not associative.

Comment: @user2355058:  you absolutely do not want them the same size.  You want one fraction bar to be larger to show which division is last.  That is the source of your problem.

Comment: And that part of the problem: the variation in size is a way of designating  the grouping.

Comment: @user2355058 if you want to be understood, you need to write clearly.

Comment: Thanks -- I guess I just need to go retake algebra 1 and pre algebra. wish me luck

Comment: No, you need not deliberately obscure your meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have been confused by the implied parentheses in the size of the fraction bars.  Your first rule is $$\frac A{\left(\frac BC\right)}=\frac {AC}B$$ which you can establish by multiplying the fraction by $\frac CC$.  You have written the second the same way on the left,
$$\frac B{\left(\frac CA\right)}=\frac {B}{CA}$$
which is incorrect.  I suspect you meant to write 
$$\frac {\left(\frac BC\right)}A=\frac {B}{CA}$$
which is correct and can be established by multiplying by $\frac CC$.  The only clue in what you wrote is the size of the fraction bars and your top one is the largest in both cases.  It is hard to see that in my browser, but the strucure of your MathJax makes it clear.

Comment: His MathJax is not clear anyway.

Comment: @WeijunZhou:  I looked at the source and saw how the fractions were specified

Comment: The bigger division is simplified last, am I correct?

Comment: @RossMillikan This is what I see: \$\$
\frac{A}{\cfrac{B}{C}} \equiv{\frac{AC}{B}}
\$\$

and

\$\$
\frac{B}{\cfrac{C}{A}} \equiv{\frac{B}{CA}}
\$\$. I don't see any difference.

Comment: This is just another variation on the "Does a/bc mean (a/b)c or a/(bc)?" question.

Comment: @YashJain Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no such "rules" for using them, $A>B>C$ or $B>A>C$ don't have to be conditions. To make fractions like these seem simpler, think of division as the "opposite" of multiplication. I'll show you what I mean.

$\cfrac{A}{\frac{B}{C}}$

is equal to $\cfrac{A}{1}$*$\cfrac{C}{B}=\cfrac{AC}{B}$

The second fraction you put up is incorrect.

$\cfrac{B}{\frac{C}{A}}$

is equal to $\cfrac{B}{1}*\cfrac{A}{C}=\cfrac{BA}{C}$

Think of division $\cfrac{A}{B}$ as multiplication of $A*\cfrac{1}{B}$

Comment: I use symbolab to check my work -- are they an approved tool? They say they used the incorrect one as part of a soln -- maybe the translation from latex to plain text is just wrong on their end? Also, you can use cfrac for nicer fractions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: All online calculators should be correct **as long as you are specifying the parenthesis**. For instance, $A/B*C$ is not the same as $A/(B*C)$

Comment: Ross Millikan's answer is far superior, @user2355058.

Comment: @Shaun which makes it a reason for you to downvote my corrct answer which i posted before the other person